# Trackpad gesture to open the widget sidebar?

Tags: trackpad, big-sur

What is the exact touchpad gesture to open the widget sidebar?

Comment: If you mean display the widgets, swipe left from the right edge with two fingers (enable it here: System Preferences > Trackpad > More Gestures > Notification Center).

Comment: It's enabled but doesn't do it. Using two fingers in the top right corner where the time is displayed.

Comment: You need to swipe left physically from off the trackpad (i.e. the palmrest) and onto the trackpad. You don't have to have the cursor in the top right to do this. You can have the cursor wherever on the screen

Comment: @orschiro When I first enabled it, I had some trouble getting macOS to recognize the gesture. Instead of displaying the notification center, I swiped a page in Safari (Safari was the foreground app). I had to switch to a space without any open apps and try again. Now it works.

Comment: @AVelj this is it! Want to add as answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to swipe left physically from off the right edge of the trackpad (i.e. the palmrest) and onto the trackpad. You don't have to have the cursor in the top right to do this. You can have the cursor wherever on the screen.